# Get Ipv6 Full Format In php

Tags: php, ipv6

I have an IPv6 like:

```
2001:cdba::3257:9652
```

I want get IPv6 in full format like:

```
2001:cdba:0000:0000:0000:0000:3257:9652
```

Does has any function in java to do that? And how to compress a IPv6 full format? Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

i do with this function

```
$ip  ="2001:db0:0:123a:0:0:0:30";
function expand($ip){
    $hex = unpack("H*hex", inet_pton($ip));         
    $ip = substr(preg_replace("/([A-f0-9]{4})/", "$1:", $hex['hex']), 0, -1);
    return $ip;
}

$rt = expand($ip);
echo "<br>".$rt."<br>";//2001:0db0:0000:123a:0000:0000:0000:0030
```